# Do topological inductive dimension(s) and algebraic dimension match for topological vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Does the notion of small or large inductive dimension for a topological vector space match the notion of dimension given by the cardinality of a basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a *real* vector space (so with scalars $\Bbb R$) and $X$ is finite dimensional as a vector space, then the linear-space dimension coincides with the topological dimension (either the inductive ones, or the covering one). This is initially due to Brouwer (and later also Hurewicz) and non-trivial. It was Brouwer who corrected a wrong proof by Lebesgue to this effect (and before that it was an open problem for some time).

For infinite-dimensional $\Bbb R$-spaces, the topological dimension functions just assign value $\infty$ and make no finer distinctions (if not finite dimensional, they're called (weakly) infinite dimensional, but most spaces in practice are actually strongly infinite-dimensional, as it's called). There *are* ordinal-valued inductive dimensions, but these have not been studied much, and there is no easy relation (AFAIK) with algebraic dimension.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Engelking covers some ordinal-valued notions of inductive dimension in Theory of Dimensions and I’ve been meaning to give it a go, I’ll post if any interesting relation pops up.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't a connection between these. Consider e.g. $\mathbb{C}$ (with the usual topology) as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space vs. as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space vs. as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Its topological dimension is $2$, but its algebraic dimension is $2$, $1$, or $2^{\aleph_0}$ depending on which field of scalars we pick.

Comment: Good call — in the case of finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$- vector spaces do they match? How about infinite dimensional real vector spaces?